# Android system dialog popup cannot cancel

Tags: android, dialog, system

I am trying to close the system dialog but the dialog has only "ok" button and cannot cancelable on back button. I tried two ways. first in broadcast

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(closeDialog);}
```

second

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean isTrue) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(isTrue);

    if (!isTrue){
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```

but no one works. Any help

[image]

Comment: what dialog are you trying to close?

Comment: Have the user click the "OK" button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
// User cancelled the dialog}});

Comment: Its system dialog and I can't change it programmatically.